# Updating row numbers in chunks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to do batching of rows, so that batch jobs will pick up appropriate records for processing. Currently I write several update queries for it like so:

```
update salestable
set BATCHNO=1
where status=1 and id in (
select top 1000 id from salestable where status=1)

update salestable
set BATCHNO=2
where status=1 and id in (
select top 1000 id from salestable where status=1
and batchno not in (1))


update salestable
set BATCHNO=3
where status=1 and id in (
select top 1000 id from salestable where status=1
and batchno not in (1,2))
...
...
... on and on
```

Is there a single query available for this?

Comment: Your subqueries make no sense, because you are using `TOP` without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I'd say use `row_number` to generate a consecutive sequence ordered by ID. You can calculate the batch number by doing `seq mod 1000` (or actually `((seq-1) mod 1000) + 1`). Use that select as input for the update statement.

Comment: @GolezTrol For me division does the job instead of modulus since I want to give numbering to rows in batch of 1000's. For eg 1st 1000's as 1, next 1000 as 2, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, yes, division of course. But you get the general idea  :o) Sorry I didn't have time to figure out a syntactically correct, SQL server compatible version of this, but I see Tim has helped you out there.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yep. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, BATCHNO, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE status = 1
)

UPDATE cte
    SET BATCHNO = ((rn - 1) / 1000) + 1;
```

Note carefully that I have assumed an ordering for the batches using the `id` column.  In your current subqueries, you are using `TOP` without `ORDER BY`, which is a fairly undefined thing.  We can only speak of the top 1000 records with regard to some ordering.

---

Edit by MYGz:
Though I used division but I ran into an issue where I am unable to accommodate 1 extra batchno resulting from incomplete division.

So modulus as posted and suggested earlier is a better option as it won't give an extra batchno.

Comment: For me division does the job instead of modulus since I want to give numbering to rows in batch of 1000's. For eg 1st 1000's as 1, next 1000 as 2, and so on. Update your answer, I'll accept.